# Trouble fetching data from DP04 table using acs.R

Tags: r, census

I am using the acs.R package and I am having trouble collecting data from the DP tables and S tables.  The tables beginning with B are fine though.  Here is an example of my code and the error I receive:

```
national = geo.make(us="*")

Race_US <- acs.fetch(endyear = 2015, span = 1, geography = national, 
table.number = "DP04", col.names = "pretty")

Warning message:
In (function (endyear, span = 5, dataset = "acs", keyword, table.name,  :
  Sorry, no tables/keyword meets your search.
  Suggestions:
   try with 'case.sensitive=F',
   remove search terms,
   change 'keyword' to 'table.name' in search (or vice-versa)
```

For some reason it is unable to find the table. I have tried acs.lookup with various keywords that should work and still nothing.

Comment: Having same issue with DP04 table - were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using the acs.R package.

The problem here is with the "DP" tables: although they are available through the census api, they are not fetched via the acs.R package, since they are in a different format -- not really "raw data" as much as pre-formatted tables made from data found in other places.  That said, you should be able to find the underlying data in other tables that *are* available with acs.fetch.